# Visual Studio 2008 Release Installer packaging debug binaries

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, installation, debugging, release

I've been maintaining a Windows forms application written in C# for some time now used in our company, and every now and again when I'm putting a new release out, the release build of the installer that I generate packages up a debug version of the class library that is part of the project.

I've specified the release version of the primary output, which is fine, but the class library DLL picked up as a detected dependency quite often seems to pick the debug version.

Looking in my setup project, at the properties of the class library, the source is pointing at the version in the debug directory. I can't edit this value as it is greyed out.

If I select release in the toolbar, and refresh dependencies, the problem is corrected, but when I'm preparing a release I use the batch build option. why does batch building not deal with this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make long story short: **it is a bug, don't use batch builds**.

[Long story anyway, from  msdn (scroll down a bit).](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpide/thread/33c0f18f-ee07-4dc1-92ed-42cffe572c3a)
Favourite quotes:

1. "MS seems to have mixed feelings about batch builds."
2. "However I don't think it'll get fixed anytime soon."

Cheers